# codeigniter min engine causing excesive cpu usage

Tags: codeigniter-2, min

Recently one of my websites was suspended due to excessive CPU usage. Here is the e-mail from the hosting company:

> Hello Sanil,
>
> As you probably aware, here at Just Host we proactively monitor all
>   our servers to ensure that our clients websites are loading as fast as
>   possible at all times. During this routine monitoring we have found
>   that your account is utilizing an excessive amount of system
>   resources, and we have been forced to suspend your site as per our
>   terms and conditions '10% CPU/MEM/MySQL Policy'
>
> For your reference, here is a copy of your usage report:

```
juks0n jukson.com Top Process %CPU 16.0 /usr/bin/php
/home/juks0n/public_html/min/index.php Top Process %CPU 12.0
/usr/bin/php /home/juks0n/public_html/min/index.php Top Process %CPU
11.7 /usr/bin/php /home/juks0n/public_html/min/index.php 

%MEM 12.93
```

Does anyone have any idea why `min` is causing this problem or have any suggestions for resolving this issue?

Comment: erm they suspended you for using 10% cpu, some of the sites i know of run in the 75% bracket, just sounds like they dont want you to do anything that could take the processor over 10%, I would change hosting, I mean it could just be a large MySQL query

Comment: Agreed. Switch hosts.  You should be in a virtualization container (of which you get to use 100% of the resources).  This raises waaay too many red flags...